# How to get itertool.product to generate strings instead of list of chars and then brace each string with additional strings?

Tags: python, string

I don't know much about python data structures but basically I'm generating all permutations of letters :

```
import, itertools, string    
k = itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat = 2)
list(k)
[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ..., ('z', 'x'), ('z', 'y'), ('z', 'z')]
```

I need to perform 2 operations on the generator `k` that will preserve it as a generator if possible :

1) Concatenate each list so `list(k)` would return :

```
["aa", "ab", ..., "zy", "zz"]
```

2) Brace each string with aditional strings `"str1"` and `"str2"` so after step 1) and step 2) `list(k)` would return :

```
["str1aastr2", "str1abstr2", ...,"str1zystr2","str1zzstr2"]
```

How to proceed to get a generator that looks like that so I can feed it to scrapy's `start_urls` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new generator that will produce the desired values:

```
import itertools
import string

def g():
    start = ["str1"]
    end = ["str2"]
    for item in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=2):
        yield "".join(start + list(item) + end)
```

Example:

```
>>> gen = g()
>>> list(gen)[:10]
['str1aastr2', 'str1abstr2', 'str1acstr2', 'str1adstr2', 'str1aestr2', 'str1afstr2', 'str1agstr2', 'str1ahstr2', 'str1aistr2', 'str1ajstr2']
```

After `gen = g()` you've got a generator object that you can use with Scrapy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generator expression to do the complete action. Not sure I understand the need to keep it as a generator if you immediately call `list()` on it:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> k = ('str1{}str2'.format(''.join(s)) for s in it.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=2))
>>> next(k)
'str1aastr2'
>>> list(k)
['str1abstr2', 'str1acstr2', 'str1adstr2', 'str1aestr2', ...]
```

Note: the `str1aastr2` was consumed by the `next(k)`

Or a slightly different construct:

```
>>> k = (f'str1{c1}{c2}str2' for c1, c2 in it.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=2))
>>> next(k)
'str1aastr2'
>>> next(k)
'str1abstr2'
```

Comment: nice one liner but I think it doesn't preserve the generator datastructure I'm not sure

Comment: It's very easy to preserve the generator replace `[...]` with `(...)` and it becomes a generator expression.